# asynchronous API calls in apache beam

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

As the title says, I want to make asynchronous API calls in apache beam using python.

Currently, I am calling the API inside a DoFn for each element in the Pcollection.

**DoFn code**

```
class textapi_call(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key


    def setup(self):
        self.session = requests.session()

    def process(self, element):
        address = element[3] + ", " + element[4] + ", " + element[5] + ", " + element[6] + ", " + element[7]
        url = findplace_url(address, api_key=self.api_key)
        params = {"inputtype": "textquery",
                  "fields": "name,place_id,geometry,type,icon,permanently_closed,business_status"}
        start = time.time()
        res = self.session.get(url, params=params)
        results = json.loads(res.content)
        time_taken = time.time() - start

        return [[element[0], address, str(results), time_taken]]
```

**pipeline code:**

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    lines = p | ReadFromText(input_file,skip_header_lines=1)
    lines_list = lines | "to list" >> beam.Map(parse_csv)
    res = lines_list | "API calls" >> beam.ParDo(textapi_call(api_key))
```

How can I modify the code to make the API calls asynchronous or concurrent?
I could not find any examples relating to this in python.

I want to mainly improve the performance. Please let me know if there is another way to make the API calls faster in beam apart from horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this, where you're spending most of your time waiting for external services, there are a couple of ways to speed things up.

The easiest would be to use something like [BatchElements](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.BatchElements) followed by a DoFn that would process a whole batch in parallel. This works best when the service in question has a batch API, but one can do it manually as well, e.g.

```
class ProcessBatchDoFn(beam.DoFo):
  def setup(self):
    self.session = requests.session()
    self.executor = concurrent.futures.Executor(...)

  def process(batch_of_elements):
    urls = [element_to_url(e) for e in batch_of_elements]
    for element, result in zip(
        batch_of_elements,
        self.executor.map(self.session.get, urls))
        yield element[0], url, str(result)  # or whatever is needed downstream
```

used as

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    lines = p | ReadFromText(input_file,skip_header_lines=1)
    lines_list = lines | "to list" >> beam.Map(parse_csv)
    res = lines_list | beam.BatchElements() |  beam.ParDo(ProcessBatchDoFn())
```

Maybe using something like https://github.com/ross/requests-futures could make this simpler.

This will work well as long as the URLs all take about the same amount of time to fetch. Anther option would be to do rolling requests, e.g.

```
def ExpensivePerElementDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def setup(self):
    self.executor = concurrent.futures.Executor(...)

  def start_bundle(self):
    self.pending = []

  def process(element):
    self.pending.append(self.executor.submit(fn, element))
    yield from self.flush_done()
    while len(self.pending) > MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      yield from self.flush_done()

  def flush_done(self):
    done = [ix for ix, future in enumerate(self.pending) if future.done()]
    for ix in reversed(done):
      future = self.pending.pop(ix)
      yield future.result()

  def finish_bundle(self):
    for future in self.pending():
      yield future.result()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the google geocoding API and I don't think it has a batch API(correct me if I am wrong). Also, I was wondering if there would be any performance difference between the two ways you mentioned. Since in both methods we are basically doing concurrent calls for a batch of elements, what is the difference apart from using beam.batchElements() vs manually batching? Could you also elaborate on why method 1 works well only when all URLs take the same amount of time?

Comment: You're right, I don't see a bulk API for that one. As for the difference between the two methods, suppose one URL takes 10 seconds and the rest only take 1 second. With the beam.batchElements() method, it will fire off all N urls simultaneously, and then get n-1 results after 1 second, and wait for 10 seconds before getting the next batch of N urls. With the second method, it will start on a next url as soon as one is returned.

Comment: Hi @robertwb for some reason you code give me "RuntimeError: NotImplementedError" in self.pending.append(self.executor.submit(fn, element)).
If it's not too much of a problem, could you provide a working example, some kind of hello world? Thanks! 
PS: I change "fn" with my function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to generate an example using the requests-futures library.
https://github.com/ross/requests-futures

**This was @robertwb idea.**

I use the following link as a reference: [batch-writes-to-google-cloud-firestore-using-the-apache-beam-java-sdk-on-google-cloud-dataflow](https://rm3l.org/batch-writes-to-google-cloud-firestore-using-the-apache-beam-java-sdk-on-google-cloud-dataflow/)

```
class NewFunctionFn(beam.DoFn):

    def setup(self):
        self.session = FuturesSession(max_workers=30)

    def start_bundle(self):
        self.pending = []

    def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        # element : ("prefix name","some string ....") -> tuple
        prefix, text = element

        self.prefix = prefix
        self.window = window

        future = self.session.post(
            "https://api.xxxxxx.com/",
            json={"text": text},
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        )

        self.pending.append(future)

    def finish_bundle(self):
        for future in as_completed(self.pending):

            yield beam.utils.windowed_value.WindowedValue(
                value=(self.prefix,future.result().json()["response"]),
                timestamp=0,
                windows=[self.window],
            )
```

I'm starting with apache beam so any code review is welcome!
Cheers!